# Displaying value of XML string array in listView instead of the relevant stored position

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

Firstly sorry if the question title is unclear, I couldn't think how to word it concisely.

I have an app with basic database functionality to add a name, date of birth and job type of a person to a database. The job type is chosen from a spinner populated from a string array in the XML resource file;

```
<string-array name="job_type_array">
    <item>Job 1</item>
    <item>Job 2</item>
    <item>Job 3</item>
    ...
</string-array>
```

In the database the job name isn't stored, its position in the string array is stored (ie 'Job 1' is saved as the integer 0 etc)

When I then display the the contents of the database in a listView I would like to display the actual job rather than its position, but I don't know how to do this.

The code I am using for the listView is from the Android Developers example;

```
public class PersonList extends ListActivity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;

public String[] mTypeArray;
public List typeList;

private PersonDbAdapter mDbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.horses_list);
    mDbHelper = new PersonDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    mTypeArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.job_type_array);
    typeList = Arrays.asList(mTypeArray);

    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
    Cursor personCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPeople();
    startManagingCursor(personCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only    Name and job)
    String[] from = new String[]{PersonDbAdapter.KEY_NAME, PersonDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE};

    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.rowPersonName, R.id.rowPersonJobType};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter people = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.people_row, peopleCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(people);
}
```

The cursor fetchAllPeople just gets all data on every person in the database.

My question is; how do I display the actual job rather than just the position that is stored in the database. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Neatened up code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the `TextView`(?!?) in the row layout where you want to place the job title is the view with the id `R.id.rowHorseType`(in the `to` array, also I assume `PersonDbAdapter.KEY_TYPE` represents the column from the cursor with the job int values). In this case you would use a `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder` to transform the job `int` values stored in the database into actual job titles, like this:

```
people.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor,
                    int columnIndex) {
                if (view.getId() == R.id.rowHorseType) {
                    int jobInt = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                    ((TextView) view).setText(mTypeArray[jobInt]); // if the view with the id R.id.rowHorseType is a TextView!!!
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your assumptions were correct. Sorry for the confusion; I tried altering my code to a clearer example and forgot to change some bits.
This works perfectly! Thankyou for the help

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting you properly if you want to get the data from the database you should use:

```
Cursor previous_repotData = getdataBaseRecord();
Stirng stdate = getString(previous_repotData.getColumnIndexOrThrow("startDate")));
```

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I have got it working using Luksprog's answer now. Thankyou for your input though